# Sending emails using phpBitsTheater

Tags: php

I am working on this https://github.com/baracudda/phpBitsTheater PHP framework to create robust web applications. I have been assigned a task to send emails to users for password recovery. I have been working on sending emails using that framework for several days. Upto now I could not learn how to send email using this framework.
I would be glad if anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

How I solved my problem?
First I created a Google email account for my site, then created an "app token" for that account on gmail. Once I had the app token, I could use it as the "password" for my outgoing email integration settings in the framework. The *SMTP Host Address* is `smtp.gmail.com`, and *Port* is `587`. The *User Name* is the email address I created, and the *Password* is the app token. *Security* should be *TLS*. The *Default From: Address* is what would be shown in the header (and email client) as the "sender".